# How do i save a user 's profile picture with swift and load it, for the specific user logged in using firebase?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a basic user creation activity, name, email and password. I am trying to save the user's profile picture and load it in their profile page once they login. How do I do that?

I already stored the user's name and email in my database, but I am not sure how to save their profile picture. I tried searching the problem on stack overflow but most solution I found were too old.

```
func saveUserProfile(){
    let userRefrence = Database.database().reference().child("Users").childByAutoId()

    let userDictionary:[String:String] = ["name":users.name, "email" :users.userEmail]
    self.userRefrence.setValue(userDictionary)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're already using Firebase than first you'd want to save the image using Firebase Storage.

Here we grab a reference to storage and convert our image into data.

```
let fileName = NSUUID().uuidString
let profileImagesRef = Storage.storage().reference().child("profile_images/\(fileName)")

guard let uploadData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.3) else {
    return
}
```

Then we actually save our data into Firebase Storage

```
profileImagesRef.putData(uploadData, metadata: nil, completion: { (metadata, error) in
    if let error = error {
        return
    }

    // After the image has been successfully uploaded we need to grab its download url

    profileImagesRef.downloadURL(completion: { (downloadURL, error) in
        if let error = error {
            return
        }

        guard let downloadURL = downloadURL else {
            return
        }

        print("successfully fetched download URL: \(downloadURL.absoluteString)")
    })
})
```

You want to save the downloadUrl to your user model and use that to download your profile image when loading the profile.

You can read about it in the Firebase documentation.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/download-files

https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/upload-files